# Postfix dereference say((\@a)->@*) v5.22

Tags: perl

I have read about postfix dereference and I wanted to try it, but I am unable to make this simple example work.

```
use v5.22;
my @a = ('hello', 'bye', 'see you');
say((\@a)->@*);
```

I should get the array printed, but all I got was:

> Array found where operator expected at hola.pl line 3, at end of line
>     (Missing operator before ?) syntax error at hola.pl line 7, near
>   "->@"

My perl version is:

> This is perl 5, version 22, subversion 1 (v5.22.1) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi

Comment: What is your Perl version? Run `perl -v` to see the version. Also, `say((\a)->@*)` should maybe be `say((\@a)->@*)` ?

Comment: This is perl 5, version 22, subversion 1 (v5.22.1) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi

Comment: @Corion I feel sorry, I posted the code copied by hand and I had no time to see the erratas;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature is experimental in 5.22.x, quoting [perl5240delta](https://perldoc.perl.org/perl5240delta.html):

> **Postfix dereferencing is no longer experimental**
>
> Using the "postderef" and "postderef_qq" features no longer emits a warning. Existing code
>        that disables the "experimental::postderef" warning category that they previously used
>          will continue to work. The "postderef" feature has no effect; all Perl code can use
>          postfix dereferencing, regardless of what feature declarations are in scope. The 5.24
>          feature bundle now includes the "postderef_qq" feature.

Quoting [perlexperiment](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlexperiment.html):

> **Postfix dereference syntax**
>
> Introduced in Perl 5.20.0
>
> Accepted in Perl 5.24.0

This is how you would write the code for 5.20.0+. Please note that [experimental](https://metacpan.org/pod/experimental) may *not* be installed together with the default Perl package, i.e. you would need to install it separately:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use v5.20;
use strict;
use warnings;

use experimental qw(postderef);

my @a = ('hello', 'bye', 'see you');

say(@a);
say(@{ \@a });
say((\@a)->@*);

exit 0;
```

Output (`This is perl 5, version 28, subversion 1 (v5.28.1)`):

```
hellobyesee you
hellobyesee you
hellobyesee you
```

i.e. all three are equivalent.

Comment: I get the same error with `say((\@a)->@*);` in your code

Comment: The feature is experimental in 5.22.x. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Solved, thank you, this was the problem, I will compile a more recent version.

Comment: Updated my answer how to get it working with 5.20.0+

Comment: @Grinnz Fedora Perl maintainers seem to have decided to keep it as separate module. Rewording my answer.

Comment: @StefanBecker On Fedora many core modules are packaged separately from the interpreter, you need to install `perl` (this used to be named `perl-core`) to get a usable Perl.

Comment: @Grinnz I guess a side-effect of the Fedora Atomic Host cleanup, i.e. to reduce the size of a absolutely minimal installation. My current working machines are relatively new installs (less than 1 year old), hence I only got `perl-core` or `perl-interpreter` through the standard install. `dnf install perl` dragged in 70+ new packages. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 4):

The feature can be activated as follows:

```
use feature qw( postderef );
no warnings qw( experimental::postderef );
```

That can be reduced to

```
use experimental qw( postderef );
```

The `postderef` feature is also activated by `use feature ':5.24';` (and thus by `use v5.24;`), but it's activated by neither `use feature ':5.20';` nor `use feature ':5.22';` (and thus by neither `use v5.20;` nor `use v5.22;`) because the feature was still experimental in 5.20 and 5.22.

The feature didn't change between 5.20 and 5.24, so it's safe to use in 5.20 and 5.22, so it's safe to ignore the warning.

Comment: It actually doesn't need a feature at all in 5.24+, it's automatically active.